# How to get subdomain in UserProvider

Tags: security, symfony, dependency-injection, fosuserbundle

Im doing multitenant service where im validate users against:

username, password, subdomain

Me using FOSUserBundle

I would like to use UserProvider to be aware of from wchich domain its called and then make user find.

Problem is i can't get access to @request whatever i try container or set injections i got

"ScopeWideningInjectionException: Scope Widening Injection detected"

is there any proper way to extend FOSUserBundle to be request aware when validate (make user login) username ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I did it this way:

Used [SyndMultiTenantBundle](https://github.com/SyndicateTheory/SyndMultiTenantBundle) for multitenant propose with domainstrategy

and to make it work with FOSUserBundle:

1. Create new UserManager & UserRepository classes
2. Override your UserManager:loadUserByUsername method to query your repository directly
3. Compiler pass to use your custom use manager (change
   class of definition)
4. Add a listener on tenant.found to call
   $userManager->setTenant($event->getTenant()) to pass tenant into
   scope of repository

Thanks to Adrian from SyndicateTheory

It works like a charm - Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Changing the scope of UserProvider? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

```
my_user_provider:
    class: Acme\HelloBundle\UserProvider
    scope: request
    arguments: [@request]
```

Not sure if it will work in this case.  The security stuff it tricky.

An alternative might be to create a REQUEST listener, have it pull the subdomain and then have it inject it into the user provider.

Comment: it gives exactly problem i put in question: "ScopeWideningInjectionException: Scope Widening Injection detected"

Comment: Then go with the request listener.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with Symfony 2.1 I was able to give the @service_container as parameter directly in my provider and then getting the request...

Since I updated to SF 2.2, **not working anymore !**

Even if you set "scope: active", or "public: true" in your configuration.

If you try to get the request by an intermediate listener, it doesn't work too... It seems since SF2.2 that the request is not injected in time or something like that.

So here how I can get the request inside the provider, I don't know if it's clean but this is the only solution I found, I pasted the 2 solutions, for sf 2.2 and sf 2.1 :

**SF 2.2**

Provider class :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// ...

class WebsiteUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $websiteUrl;

    // ...

    public function __construct(UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;

        // Works for sf2.2, init manually the request
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $this->websiteUrl = $request->getHost();
    }

    // ...
}
```

That's it !

---

**SF 2.1**

Provider class :

```
// ...

class WebsiteUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $websiteUrl;

    // ...

    public function __construct($container, UserManager $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;

        if ($container->isScopeActive('request')) {
            $this->websiteUrl = $container->get('request')->getHost();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Configuration :

```
sybio_website.user_provider:
    class: Sybio\Bundle\WebsiteBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\WebsiteUserProvider
    arguments: [@service_container, @sybio.user_manager]
```

Comment: that would be good if somone could tell what changed 2.1 -> 2.2 it dosent work anymore

Comment: If you use a request listener then the request will part of the event.  No need to inject it.

Comment: @nicoonee did you try my solution for SF 2.2 ? It works on my project.